# Yii 2: Session Variable Disappearing

Tags: php, session, yii2

I have a controller in Yii 2.0 wherein I save session variables.

```
$session = Yii:$app->session;
$session->open();
$session['user_id'] = $userId;
```

When I try to access the session variable from another class which does not extend the Yii 2 Controller class(if I display it in the original class though, the value is there), the variable has no value.

```
$session = Yii::$app->session;
$session->open();

echo $session['user_id'];
```

Any ideas?

Here is a snippet from the model class where I'm using the session variable:

```
 public function create()
{
    $session = Yii::$app->session;
    ...
    $model->user_id = ''.$session['user_id'];
    ...

    $model->save(FALSE);

}
```

Comment: Is there anything special with the controllers? Maybe 'echo' is a problem. Did you have a look into the log?

Comment: Why you are opening the session again if it was already opened before? Also there is typo in `sesssion` name that leads to fatal error even before echo. Tested it, it's working for me. Add more information about controllers where this code is located.

Comment: @robsch, there's actually nothing special except that the other class is focused mainly on saving to the database.

Comment: @arogachev I guess the other controller is accessed in another request. AFAIK you have to open the session on each request. Correct?

Comment: Wait. I think I got it. It's careless of me. Is it possible to access session data from a model class for example?

Comment: You can use Yii::$app->session anywhere you want. You don't actually have those typing errors like in your posting?

Comment: Ok. So it's not really the case. Yes, I don't have those typos.

Comment: I added a new code snippet showing where I'm using the session variable.

Comment: Please update your posting and take all into account what @arogachev and I told or asked you. You question could be helpful for others as well. It's hard to tell with your current information.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72147/discussion-between-robsch-and-elendil).